# CLARIFAI No module named clarifai.client error

Tags: recaptcha, clarifai

I am trying out the `ReCaptcha v2` solver but it throws me an `ImportError` however i have [`clarifai-python`](https://clarifai-python.readthedocs.io/) installed.

I have tried to change `clarifai.client` to `clarifai.rest` but did not work out.

Comment: Please show us some code..